# What is the difference between b and c?

Tags: python, python-3.x

See the following code :

```
class A:
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    self.l=[]
    #self.b=self.l.append

def foo(self):
    return 3


a=[]
b=A(a.append)
c=A()
b.foo()
print (b, c)
print (len(a))
```

what is the difference between objects `b` and `c`? Specifically what is the meaning of `a.append`.

Comment: What?  `A.__init__` doesn't do anything with its arguments, so passing in `a.append` does nothing.  A just throws it away.

Comment: it's not even well indented, so class A doesn't have init

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`b` and `c` are different instances of class A. And `a.append` is a method used to append value to list.

Answer (score 1):

b=A(a.append) means nothing here since A.**init** doesn't sign any variables. So the answer is, b and c are just two objects with different allocated memory space.

Answer (score 0):

Check comment provided in code for explanation:

```
class A:
    #Constructor to Class A, args contain list of formal arguments and kwargs contains object (dict) of keyward arguments
    #(4,5,None, test = "Hello", new = True) so args have [4,5,None] and kwargs have {"test":"Hello", "new" : True} 
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
       self.l=[]
       #self.b=self.l.append

    def foo(self):
       return 3


a=[]
#a is list and mutable data structure
b=A(a.append)
#a.append - append is method to list a to put values in list a like a.append(5), a.append(6) so list a is [5,6]. Here a.append provides info to memory location. 
#b is a variable contains reference to object A at mem location X   
c=A()
#c is a variable contains reference to object A at mem location Y
#b and c difference, Ideally both are reference to object A but located at diff locations and contains their own set of values/data. 
b.foo()
print (b, c)
print (len(a))
```